# Is there anyway to reconstruct an object inside itself?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple class that is intended for options of an winforms application. There should be a method that reset options to their default values. I know I can add a separate  method to take care of this, but the code will be huge (If I add more options to the class) :

```
public SensorOptions()
{
    ShowLabelMax = ShowLabelMin = ShowLabelAvr = ShowReceivedTextBox = true;

    ChartMaxValue = 140;
    ChartMinValue = -40;

    ShowChartMinValue = ShowChartMaxValue = ShowChartAvrValue = ShowChartAvrLine = true;

    LogFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.ToString();
    LoggingEnabled = true;
}

public void ResetOptions()
{
    this = new SensorOptions(); //can not do. 'this' is read-only
}
```

I mean I can copy/paste the code from constructor into `ResetOptions()` method. But is there any smarter ways to achieve this?

Comment: Call `ResetOptions` from the constructor? Just move all your initialisation logic into `ResetOptions` and call this from the constructor. This way there's only 1 place to do all your reset/init. Obviously anything that needs to be in the constructor should be kept there, but it all looks like value reset logic which can safely sit in a method

Comment: Call `SensorOptions();` !?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Calling code should be able to cope with a new instance.

Comment: Instead of that , you can have separate method as `ResetToDefault` and call it in constructor and whereever you want to reset. Just refactor your code.

Comment: @Charleh yup....you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign `this` because you may have references to this instance of your class in your program. If you could re-construct the object by re-assigning `this`, it would mean that all references to the old instance of the class become invalid.

No matter how many options you have in your class, you initialize each of them one or the other way (because you mention  `default value` in your question - so you need to assign that default value somewhere at least once, probably in the constructor). Therefore, the solution to your problem is simple - move all initializers to the separate method and call it in the constructor, and then also call it every time you need to reset your options to their default values.

If any of your options are not assigned a default value explicitly, and use system default and you don't want to write `option=default(optionType)` for each option, you can use reflection to enumerate all fields/properties in that class and assign default values to them, like this:

```
public static object GetDefault(Type type)
{
   if(type.IsValueType) return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   return null;
}
foreach(var field in this.GetType().GetFields())
    field.SetValue(this, GetDefault(field.FieldType));
foreach(var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    prop.SetValue(this, GetDefault(prop.PropertyType));
```

Answer (score 4):

Move all of the code from the constructor into the ResetOptions method, then in your constructor call the ResetOptions method. Your initialisiation code is only in one place then.

Answer (score 2):

You have very simple architecture for your situation. In my opinion it would be better to apply a trick for this:
you have class for holding all your options (pseudo code):

```
class AllOptionsBackstage
{
   public bool ShowLabelMax { get; set; }
   public bool ShowLabelMin { get; set; }
   public bool ShowLabelAvr { get; set; }

   public AllOptionsBackstage()
   {
      // apply default values here
   }
}  

.....


class MyOptions
{
   private AllOptionsBackstage _options;

   public MyOptions()
   { 
      Reset();  
   }

   public bool ShowLabelMax 
   {
     get{ return _options.ShowLabelMax; } 
     set{ _options.ShowLabelMax = value; }
   }

   public bool ShowLabelMin 
   {
     get{return _options.ShowLabelMin;}
     set{_options.ShowLabelMin=value; }
   }

   public bool ShowLabelAvr 
   {
     get{ return _options.ShowLabelAvr;}
     set{ _options.ShowLabelAvr = value; }
   }

   public void Reset()
   {
      _options = new AllOptionsBackstage(); // will reset all your options to default
   }
}
```